# HTML mail template - Embedded images don't show

Tags: html, email, templates

I've been trying to make an HTML template to use in emails. I want to embed inline images from my computer. I'm using:

```
<img src="images/footer.png" alt="" width="100%" style="display: block;" />
```

However when I copy the template in the email, the images don't show up. I don't have that isue if instead of using an image from my computer I use an image from a web server. So apparently the imagen won't get attached to the email and that's why they don't show up. Is there any way I can get to use images from my local computer and send them with the email?

Let me explain what I want to do more in detail:

1. I Code a template in HTML
2. I display the template in a browser
   and copy it.
3. I paste it in the email.Once the template is
   in the email I edit it and add text, images, whatever I want.
4. Everytime I want to use it I just want to copy the template from
   another email and edit it.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things here:

- Make sure your image isn't hosted on a local server; your audience will not be able to see it if it is.
- I see you are using a *relative* file path. You need to use an absolute path. For example:

Instead of

```
<img src="/images/photo.gif">
```

You would code it like this:

```
<img src="http://www.website.com/email/images/photo.gif">
```

Comment: Yes I know. It's what I'm trying to do actually. I want to be able to use a local server and somehow have the image be sent with the message.